# curl batch download with multiple ranges and words

Tags: bash, curl, wget

I am trying to batch download with curl (I can also use wget), my URLs has variable like a-z and mixed words like below

```
 http://www.website.com/vairable_a/wordone.txt
 http://www.website.com/vairable_a/wordtwo.txt
 http://www.website.com/vairable_a/wordthree.txt
 http://www.website.com/vairable_b/wordone.txt
 http://www.website.com/vairable_b/wordtwo.txt
 http://www.website.com/vairable_b/wordthree.txt
```

As I need to download them in batch, I tried the following (here's the [source](http://lists.apple.com/archives/macos-x-server/2004/Nov/msg01211.html))

```
curl -f -O “http://www.website.com/vairable_[a-b]/{wordone,wordtwo,wordthree}.txt";
 curl -f -O “http://www.website.com/vairable_[a-b]/"{wordone,wordtwo,word three}".txt
```

None of them work, I'm not restricted to use curl (can use wget, etc)

Comment: Worth checkig [this link](http://blog.gypsydave5.com/2016/02/04/xargs-and-curl/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like

```
for link in http://www.website.com/vairable_{a..b}/{wordone,wordtwo,wordthree}
do
curl -f -O "$link"
done
```

Or simply

```
wget http://www.website.com/vairable_{a..b}/{wordone,wordtwo,wordthree}
```

would also do the job.

---

<sup>As an aside, bash range expansion will ***not*** work if you put string inside double quotes `{` and `}` will be treated as literals. However variable expansion do happen inside double quotes.</sup>

Comment: it does work for two variables but it didn't work (error: Argument list too long) when I had four variables but the bash script indeed worked (you have removed it here)

Comment: I guess the error has something to do with wget. I will rollback to previous answer